# Why does the scope changes while implementing Lazy function inside module pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Method 1:**

working code in normal

```
var foo1 = function() {
    var t1 = new Date();
    console.log("initialise - one time only "+this);
    foo1 = function() {
        console.log("Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) "+this);
        return t1;
    };
    return foo1();
};
```

Executing:
foo1();

output:

**First time**

initialise - one time only [object Window]

Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) [object Window]

**Every other time**

Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) [object Window]

**Method 2**

**im trying the same in a module in javascript**

```
var tt=(function(){
     var foo = function() {
        var that=this;
        var t = new Date();
        console.log("initialise - one time only" + this);
        foo = function() {
            console.log("Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) "+this);
            return t;
        };
        return foo();
    }
    return {
        foo:foo
    };
})();
```

Execute:
tt.foo();

output:

**First time**

initialise - one time only[object Object]

Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) [object Window]

**Every other time**

initialise - one time only[object Object]

Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) [object Window]

**Why does foo1 initialises again in method 2?**

**Why does the scope of this changes inside the module pattern to window in method 2?**

**How to make method 2 work like in method 1?**

*Please give a conceptual explanation what is wrong with method 2 . Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see these lines:

```
initialise - one time only[object Object]
Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) [object Window]
```

in every call of `tt.foo()` because the reference to the initial `foo` is kept in the return object ({ foo: foo }); So you're not executing:

```
foo = function() {
    console.log("Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) "+this);
    return t;
};
```

but you're executing:

```
function () {
    var that=this;
    var t = new Date();
    console.log("initialise - one time only" + this);
    foo = function() {
        console.log("Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) "+this);
        return t;
    };
    return foo();
}
```

The first log is `initialise - one time only[object Object]` because you're calling the method with the context of the:

```
{ foo: foo }
```

That's like to call:

```
var a = {
   test: function () {
      console.log(this);
   }
}
```

Here will be logged the `a` object. In the second console.log foo is not referenced by the anonymous object ( `{ foo: foo }` ) so it's called with context `window` - something like:
`foo.apply(window)`. I hope that my explanation was clear.

**Edit**
To make the second method work like the first one you must have the right reference of `foo` at the beginning. The code bellow is fixing the issue:

```
var tt=(function(){
     var foo = (function() {
        var that=this;
        var t = new Date();
        console.log("initialise - one time only" + this);
        foo = function() {
            console.log("Executes everytime after initialising(initialise should not execute again) "+this);
            return t;
        };
        return foo;
    }());
    return {
        foo:foo
    };
})();
```

Comment: thanks for explaining. How can i make method 2 to work like method1? ie it should initialise only once

Comment: I've posted it in my edit. I'm glad that I was clear and helpful :)

Comment: hi you have made the foo function as closure, it has made tt.foo() inaccessible. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: I haven't made foo closure. I've made foo self-executing function. The only difference here is that you're getting directly reference to the inner foo (the foo that's overriding the first declared foo in tt). Here's more info about these type of functions http://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: hi Gechev, In the Edit please change return foo(); to return foo. Now it works thanks. :)